# docker commit not saving changes made by java installation

Tags: docker

I am trying to commit a image from a running container.  I have installed open-jdk 1.8 in this running container and it gets installed in /usr/lib/jvm/ folder.

But doing docker diff  doesn't reflect my changes.

One thing to observe, i am able to see folder changes if i create a folder in / partition.

Answer (score 0):

Have you mount any volume on this container?

Comment: Currently while running i am not mounting any volume on this container.

Comment: But i tried mounting -v /usr/lib/.. while starting the container but still no changes were seen using docker diff.

Comment: What version of Docker engine do you use? Binding volumes contents are not committed when you run docker commit